# Why i am getting following output from this java program?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class MyThread extends Thread 
{
    MyThread() 
    {
        System.out.print(" MyThread");
    }
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.print(" bar");
    }
    public void run(String s) 
    {
        System.out.println(" baz");
    }
}
public class TestThreads 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Thread t = new MyThread() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println(" foo");
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Hello, I am new in java and currently learning Multithreading, When I am running the above program then i am getting this particular output **MyThread foo** please explain why?

Comment: What about it weren't you expecting?

Answer (score 4):

**MyThread** comes from the constructor

**foo** comes from the `run` method which gets called when `start()` is called .

Essentially the `run()` method (which prints **baz**) is *overridden* in your `main` .

and the `run(String s)` is an *overloaded* method which has no significance here.

Answer (score 1):

It is executing the `MyThread` constructor and then executing the `run()` method .

`Thread t = new MyThread()` , you are trying to create a `MyThread` object and hence it executes the constructor.

```
MyThread() 
{
    System.out.print(" MyThread");
}
```

Then you start the thread `t.start();` , it executes the `run()` method which you have overridden in `main(String[] args)` :

```
public void run() 
{
     System.out.println(" foo");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first create an instance of `MyThread`, which calls the constructor and prints " MyThread". Then, you call `t.start();` which calls the `run` method.

Even though you defined a `run` method printing " bar", it is overriden by the one in the `main` method (that prints " foo").

Try the following:

```
Thread t = new MyThread();
t.start();
```

And see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that first when create object is invoked constructor `MyThread` and print first part of string. When you start thread, execution continue with run method and print `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The first output inside the default constructor of *MyThread*, and it *overrides* a `run()` method:

```
Thread t = new MyThread() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println(" foo");
            }
        };
```

Output:

> **Thread foo**

```
Thread t = new MyThread() ;
```

Output:

> MyThread
>   bar

Note that first one  you overrode  the `run()` method and used your custom message inside it, but the second will override `run()` by default in *MyThread* class.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `run` method when you create `Thread t`. This new implementation prints " foo", which takes priority over the one you implemented in your class MyThread which still runs its own constructor that prints "MyThread".